# Type inference when using experimental extension methods in the Dart language

Tags: dart, types, extension-methods, type-inference

When I let Dart analyze the following example ...

```
extension MyList<T> on List<T> {
  List<T> mapToList<T>(T Function(T) convert) => this.map<T>(convert).toList();
}
```

... dartanalyzer reports a type error on convert claiming "The argument type 'T Function(T)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'T Function(T)'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)". I'd like to understand why I made a mistake before I file an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map method is defined as 
`Iterable<T> map<T>(T f(E e)) => MappedIterable<E, T>(this, f);` where E is the type of the list, which can be different from the type of the list.
So what you must do is:

```
extension MyList<E> on List<E> {
  List<T> mapToList<T>(T convert(E e)) => this.map<T>(convert).toList();
}
```

Comment: Ok, still there are two problems with that: (1.) A mapping (usually) happens within one type:  map<T>(T f(T e));  (2.) the error message "The argument type 'T Function(T)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'T Function(T)" is misleading.

Comment: I think that the first part of the error `The argument type 'T Function(T)'` refers to your functions definition (`T Function(T) convert`), and the second part `can't be assigned to the parameter type 'T Function(T)` refers to the map definition (`T f(E e)`) so they are actually different generic types

Comment: The problem is that you have two different type variables named `T`, one bound by the extension and one bound by the extension method. That's why changing the name of one of them allows you to write the correct type - you need to refer to the extension type variable in the method signature, but the type variable was shadowed in the original code. The message is technically correct, it's just that it's referring to different `T`'s in different places. I'd perhaps file an issue asking for the message to disambiguate the `T` names, say as `T#0` and `T#1` or something.